# How to make a regex to recognise a specific pattern of words

Tags: php, regex, ip-address, port-number

I'm poor in regex, but for some reason I left no choice but to use it.

I'm trying to extract a list of "Port number" and their respective "IP address" from a webpage's table. And because it is a dynamic webpage that using AJAX and PHP stuff to generate dynamic content, thus all table elements doesn't have any id or class or any unique things. I had already eliminates all `/t, /r and /n` using `str_replace`, which the whole content contains only words and spaces.

Here are the example of port and ip addr:

Port - Fa0/0, Gi1/0/2.100, Ethernet01, GigaEther-01 (contains upper and lower case, dot, dash, slash and numbers, and it shouldn't be more than 16 characters, no spaces)

IP adrr - 123.123.123.123, 1.1.12.12, 123.12.1.1 (no difference with common ip addr)

But fortunately, all "port" and "Ip address" are followed by either a port image or ip image., like

```
...<img border='0' src='images/port.png' width='18' heigh='18'>Fa0/0</td>... OR
...<img border='0' src='images/ip.png' width='18' heigh='18'>1.1.1.1</td>...
```

I believe there are no spaces between the port/IP and the img/td tag. Thus I'm able to use it as a pattern for extracting them, so I used the following patterns:

Port -

```
$pattern = "/<img border\='0' src='images\/port\.png' width\='18' height\='18'>([a-zA-Z0-9\/ _-]{1,15})<\/td>/";
```

IP addr -

```
$pattern = "<img border\='0' src\='images\/ip\.png' width\='18' height\='18'>\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b <\/td>/";
```

and followed by 
    `preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches);`
.
.
.

But both of them return nothing to me, then I tried the following patterns:

Port -

```
$pattern = "/<img border\='0' src='images\/port\.png' width\='18' height\='18'>(.*)<\/td>/";
```

IP addr -

```
$pattern = "<img border\='0' src\='images\/ip\.png' width\='18' height\='18'>(.*)<\/td>/";
```

...

But these pattern will return something like

```
<img border\='0' src='images\/port\.png' width\='18' height\='18'>Fa0/0
<\/td>....(Followed by a bunch of unwanted text and code)
......<\/td>
```

Because the `(.*)` will consider anyting between the `<img....>` and a `</td>` as a valid match

And also, I tried only specific IP address regex,`$pattern = "/\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b/";`

It return only the IP addresses to me (like 111.22.3.119), but unfortunately some of the link url in the webpage contains ip address as well which is not I want.

Then I tried `$pattern = "/\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}<\/td>\b/";`, it returns nothing...

Appreciate any ppl who are willing to help me on this, thanks.

*** Edit 1 ***

I tried `$pattern = "/\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b<\/td>/";`, it works, don't know why, but still figuring how to solve the Port regex....

Comment: A simple thought: You'll likely get more from `([^>]*)` than `(.*)`.  Regex default is "greedy" which can be bad if it makes you skip a start or end tag.  (Also, did you remove all line endings?!! put them back in if they are available!!!  Or even add some after certain tag ends...)  Regex is a line-oriented tool.

Comment: As stated above, I'm really poor in regex, may I know what does `([^>]*` mean? What do you mean for "remove all line endings"? I did removed all the `\n` because I did faced sometimes the code is something like `<img...>Fa0/0(next line here)</td>` which caused my pattern not working. Appreciate you could enlighten me some more on this, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$pattern1 = '#<img[^>]+>([a-z][\w./-]{1,16})</td>#i';
$pattern2 = '#<img[^>]+>([\d]{1,3}\.[\d]{1,3}\.[\d]{1,3}\.[\d]{1,3})</td>#';
```

Comment: Pattern2 works for me!! But for Pattern1, it mixed the output of pattern2 with the Port numbers, when I tried `$pattern = "#<img id\='rmcode5' border\='0' src='images\/port\.png' width\='18' height\='18'>([\w./-]{1,16})</td>#";` it only return few of them but not all, anyway, Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: @user2619841 - Do the Port ids always start with a letter, or is there some other way to distinguish between the two?

Comment: @user2619841 - I changed pattern1 on the assumption that they start with a letter. If that's not the case, please let me know.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, the `id\='rmcode5'` is actually writen by me in an edited dummy code, in the real webpage it doesn't exist. Anyway, your edited pattern1 WORKS!! Thanks A lot!!